# TypeError: must be pygame.Surface, not tuple. Python/Pygame noobie

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

Hello stack overflow users!

I have written this code and it programs to draw lines whenever you click on the pygame screen, but when I run the program, I get an error message saying `"TypeError: must be pygame.Surface, not tuple."`.  I attempted to mess around with the program, but i had no luck.  I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me figure out what's wrong with the code.  Thanks! The code is on the bottom.  Thanks again!

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_mode((800,600), 0, 32)

myWindow = ((800,600),0,32)
color = (200,155,64)
points = []

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            points.append(event.pos)
        if len(points) > 1:
            pygame.draw.line(myWindow, color, False, points, 5)

     pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: At what line do you get the error? I think this `myWindow = ((800,600),0,32)` should be this instead: `myWindow = Surface((800,600),0,32)`

Comment: yeah it was that line.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think `my window` should be like this not `tuple` please go through [this](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@g@a@GameDevelopment-HEAD@examples@pygame@raspberry_pi@python_games@drawing.py/19/pygame.draw.line)

```
myWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600), 0, 32)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that myWindow is just a tuple, not a surface. Pygame cannot draw anything onto it. You must either make myWindow the display, then you can draw onto it, or you initialise another display and make myWindow a mere Surface, then it works too.

First approach:

```
myWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), 0, 32)

# Rest of the code goes here

pygame.draw.line(myWindow, color, False, points, 5)
pygame.display.update()
```

Second approach:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), 0, 32)
myWindow = pygame.Surface((800, 600)).convert()

#Rest of the code goes here

screen.blit(myWindow, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `myWindow` in your code is a tuple, while it should be:

```
myWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600), 0, 32)
```